# How do i choose an image with a suffix from within attributes inspector for an image view?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I just started learning iOS developing, and i'm reading along with a tutorial for an universal app. The first step is to set an background image to both the `Main_iPhone.storyboard`and `Main_iPad.storyboard`.

I dragged and dropped an image view on the iPhone storyboard, used the attributes inspector to set the image to: `background-menu.png`, which i was able to choose from in the drop down for images.

Turing to the iPad storybord now, trying to do the same procedure as for the iPhone storyboard except i was told in the tutorial to choose the background image of: `background-menu~ipad.png`, which i don't seem to have access to from the: attributes inspector -> image -> drop-down-list.

In the "main" folder `images`i have 9 different images, but the ones showing in the attributes inspector for the image views are the three images not having any suffix like: `~ipad`, `@2x`, `@2x~ipad`.

Is there a way to get these images showing so that i can use them, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I gave answer for your question. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ symbol in the image name is used to specify "Device Specific Images". You select "background-menu.png" for iPad also from attributes inspector. iOS runtime will automatically pick "background-menu~iPad.png" if you use an iPad simulator/device to run your example.